# How to get number of a special bar in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get number of a bar in pine script.
For example i want find the highest bar for each 24 bars.
And i need the number of that bar not the value.
I tried

```
Highest(high,24)
```

But it returns value!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`highesbars()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_highestbars):

```
//@version=4
study("")
hi = highest(high,24)
hiIndex = - highestbars(high, 24)
hiBarIndex = bar_index[hiIndex]

plot(hi, "hi")
plot(hiIndex, "hiIndex")
plot(hiBarIndex, "hiBarIndex")
```